# Callback vs object reference

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, callback

Design question: Suppose we have parent and child object. Sometimes child object says "Parent, you've got to update your state." So, is there any critical difference between

1. Passing parent **object reference** into child contructor

and

2. Passing parent object **callBack function** into child constructor

of course, Except the case when child has to be revoked any chance to affect parent object other than using this callBack function.

Comment: You wrote: "Parent, you've got to update your state", in this case I would go for a delegate. In some situations I use also the contructor to pas in the parent, it depends much on the relation between the two objects. I do not believe there is a critical difference, ony a different need.

Comment: I would say take a look at Mediator https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/mediator. IF you don't need something as complicated as this, I would opt for delegate (the proto-interface as I call it). It's always better to depend on a "contract" than a class. Also, I would avoid at any cost that Parent knows about Child or vice-versa unless we're talking trees/polymorphism/LSP.

Comment: This is totally subjective, so pick your favorite. However, these days we tend to like *Decoupling*, which is not part of your options. So pub/sub decoupled messages, event aggregators, mediator pattern are all very common

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a good case for the observer pattern especially if the child doesn't really need any state information from the parent. And if the parent wants to ignore the child (sadly happens so often) you can simply unsubscribe from the event.

```
class Parent
{
  public Parent(Child child)
  {
    Child = child;
    Child.UpdateYourStatus += ComputeNewStateAndOutput;
  }

  Child Child {get; set;}

  private void ComputeNewStateAndOutput(sender, e) { ... }

  public void DisownChild()
  {
    //You are no longer my son (sigh, heard that one before)
    Child.UpdateYourStatus -= ComputeNewStateAndOutput;
  }
}

class Child
{
  public event EventHandler UpdateYourStatus;
}
```

Comment: Here you created a dependency of `Child` class for Parent. Means you can not create Parent without child. Also this is 1-1 relationship what if there are multiple childs and Few of them are disposed, How the Parent will know to unsubscribe them?

Comment: Just because I wrote my sample with Child in the constructor doesn't force the object to be a dependency and you can arbitrarily choose how to assign, and manage instances. Furthermore if you don't want Parent to have a dependency on Child why would Parent care when a child went out of scope or was collected by GC. Guess what no event will fire from said Child and we're none the worse.

Comment: If parent is subscribed to child's event it won't be collected by GC. One of the reason of Memory Leak. That's why there's WeakReference subscription preferred over this. These are the questions that you one should think during design itself.

Answer (score -1):

Your two choices are basically the same thing underneath, so you could feel free to choose your own preferred flavour of syntactic sugar. In both cases there's a callback function signature defined in some type (a class or interface in the first case, a delegate type in the second case) and an object reference (passed in explicitly in the first case, or bound up in a delegate instance in the second case).

Microsoft do have some guidelines on when you might want to choose one over another: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/2e759bdf-7ca4-4005-8597-af92edf6d8f0

One good reason to choose an object reference/interface over a callback is that you know you are definitely going to invoke multiple callbacks on the parent. It makes sense to pass in a single reference implementing an interface that defines all those callbacks, rather than having to create a bunch of delegate instances and pass them all in together.

Conversely, if you know you're going to want multiple different implementations of the callback for a single object, eg. because yo uwant to respond in quite different ways to the callback being invoked by different children, it might make more sense to use function pointers/delegates, but in either case you're not *forced* to choose one option over the other.